# Adjoint catchments missing in Arc Hydro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, arc-hydro, catchment

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

I have to calculate the upstream river catchments of all my small river catchments. As you can see in the picture below, there are catchments missing in a weird looking shape. Created with Arc Hydro tool "Adjoint Catchment Processing" after I created the catchments following the usual way from a DEM.

Do you have any idea why there are no adjoint catchments included at these white strips?

The white stripes seem to follow some, but not all, of the channel network. I add a picture of the stream network here below.

I don't really know the size of the river. It is a whole catchment, so the widths will vary a lot between the main stem and smaller tributaries.
The polygons have a size of a few hundret sqm to maximum 2.5 sqkm.
The DEM has a resolution of 25m*25m.

We are looking at the full catchment in the picture, its roughly 132km x 64km.

[image: Adjoint Catchments]

[image: Adjoint stream]

Comment: Looks like the white strips are (possibly) following a channel network? What is the size of the river (width) relative to the individual polygons? What is the resolution of your DEM? What scale are we looking at here?

Comment: They seem to follow a stream, yes. But not the whole stream. I add a picture of the stream in the original post. 
Sorry I did not mention all the details. I will add them to the original post as well! Thank you!!

Comment: I don't use Arc products, so I might be barking up the wrong tree. Did you fill your DEM's holes? Also, is your DEM clipped to the shape you show here, or is it a rectangle? It looks like all the holes are connected to the extents of the watershed, so it could be that the algorithm can't find a drainage divide along the river.

Comment: Yes, I did fill holes (so called sinks) in the DEM before starting the river and catchment delineation. The DEM is clipped in the shape you can see here.

Comment: If I were you, I'd try again without clipping the DEM to the extents of the watershed. I would do that as a final step.

Comment: Or at least buffer your watershed extent a little bit.

Comment: I tried this with different sizes of buffers. But unfortunately it doesnt work. ArcMap always crashes at the "Stream Segmentation" tool. I have no idea why. Any more ideas? Or is there an alternative to calculate the upstream catchments?

Comment: Sorry, I can't offer much help as I'm not familiar with Arc products. It would help if you posted the error messages you get. One of my guesses is that you are running out of memory--this is a large DEM you're using. You could see if QGIS (free) is able to do what you want without error: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hydro.html

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of trial and error, and help from @Jon, I somehow got it fixed.

I am guessing my (stupid) mistake was that I manually had split an upstream-catchment, which was too big. This resulted in a double ID and probably confused the whole tool. Unfortunately I could not remember I even did that until I spotted it.